# How can I use color syntax highlighting to show commented part of a thymeleaf template in Spring Tool Suite/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, thymeleaf, syntax-highlighting, spring-tool-suite

I would like to use Spring Tool Suite's color syntax highlighting to show which part of a thymeleaf template are being commented.
More precisely, I want this :

```
some html with normal colors
<!--/*-->
   this par is shown in very light grey
<!--*/-->
more html with normal color
```

This would be extremely useful when dealing with templates with lots of large commented parts.

Is there currently any Eclipse plugin that could work to do that, and if not, how would I implement one?

Comment: Did you take a look at the Thymeleaf Plugin for Eclipse from the marketplace?

Comment: Yes, the plugin doesn't add this feature, and afaict doesn't add anything to the base html color syntax highlighting

Comment: In case you open and edit the thymeleaf template file with the generic editor in Eclipse, you could take a look at the tm4e project: https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e -  it allows you to define TextMate grammars for specific content types - which would mean that you would need to find or implement a Textmate grammar definition that does what you are aiming for here.